# Hibernate Insert foreign key from forms

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entity:

1)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "depId")
    private Department department;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
    private Set<Equipment> equipment = new HashSet<Equipment>();
```

2)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    private int depId;
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<User>();
```

How can I write HQL query, to INSERT values to User. Not from other table. I have JSP form where insert forms. I want to add values from thats forms. 
And I have a problem with 'delete' method.

UserDAOImpl:

```
@Override
    public User findByUserName(String username) {
        return (User) getSession().get(User.class, username);
    }

@Override
    public void delete(String username) {
        getSession().delete(findByUserName(username));
    }
```

When I use this method, it delete 'department' in Department and 'user_role' in UserRole table. But I want to delete only user.

**UPDATE**

This problem fixed. But I have the second problem. I have second Entity like Depatment named UserRole. And there is same methods. I need method:

UserRoleDAOImpl:

```
@Override
public Set<UserRole> findByRole (Set<UserRole> userRole){

}
```

DepartmentDAOImpl:

```
@Override
public Department findByDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    List<Department> departments = getSession()
            .createQuery("select d from Department d where d.name =:departmentName")
            .setParameter("departmentName", departmentName).list();
    return departments.size() == 0 ? null : departments.get(0);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("users") User user, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    department = departmentService.findByDepartmentName(user.getDepartment().getName());
    user.setDepartment(department);
    userRole = userRoleService.findByRole(user.getUserRole());
    user.setUserRole(userRole);
    userService.update(user);
    model.addObject("allUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
    model.setViewName("superAdmin");
    return model;
}
```

I dont know how to write `userRoleService.findByRole(user.getUserRole())`. It doesnt work properly.

Comment: You do not Need to write any query to save an object. use the entityManager.persists() method

Comment: But how can I add foreign key "department" ?

Comment: It will be done by hibernate if you set department to user and user to department

Comment: What you mean set department to user and user to department? Do you mean what I write in entity?

Comment: I mean the Point where you create the object call `user.setDepartment` and `department.setUsers(ListOfusers).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using annotations you need to read about the hibernate transactions for insertions to db.Hoping you already created a table in db .

You can create SessionFactory object for your application and use Criteria api to persist your form values to db.
Please find a sample links

> ```
> http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/08/spring-crud-example-using-many-to-one.html#.V8aQp_l97IU
> ```

If you still want to write queries only then you can use criteria with hql

> ```
> https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/
> ```

Thanks
Pradeep